# Link two elements together so changing contents of one automatically changes contents of the other Javascript/Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Is it possible to link two elements together so changing contents of one automatically changes contents of the other using jquery or angular?

I have an app where I want the title of an element, which appears a few times throughout the app, to be the same. So for example, when i click on one button called "open window 1", it opens window 1 and when i click on another button also called "open window 1" it also opens window 1. 
What im trying to achieve is if i change the title of 1 button, to try to make it change the title of the other button in real time. Remember i have around 20 different buttons on the app, where each has a twin that should be linked together.

In basic terms i just want to link the two buttons together so they are like a mirror image of each other. Is this some feature/function Angular JS has?

Comment: Not sure about linking them per se, but you can create some global module which each of the pairs pull the title and the `onClick` function from, and any updates would be made to the module

Comment: whats an example of a global module that you're referring to?

Comment: I posted a brief answer outlining what you could do. Disclaimer I haven't used Angular in a long while so this may have to be edited to work better

Answer (score 1):

The last time I used Angular was a while ago, and it was mostly with Angularjs rather than Angular, so this is just a brief gist to give you an idea of what I mean, which you'd have to tailor to your needs

You could do something like creating a global module somewhere, such as:

`buttons.ts`:

```
interface ButtonInfo {
    title: string,
    onClick: Function
}

const button1: ButtonInfo = {
    title: 'Open Window 1',
    onClick: openWindow1()
};
const updateButton1 = update => {
    if (update.title) button1.title = update.title;
    if (update.onClick) button1.onClick = update.onClick;
};

const button2: ButtonInfo = {
    title: 'Open Window 2',
    onClick: openWindow2()
};
const updateButton2 = update => {
    if (update.title) button2.title = update.title;
    if (update.onClick) button2.onClick = update.onClick;
};

export {
    button1,
    updateButton1,
    button2,
    updateButton2,
    ButtonInfo
};
```

Then you could import this wherever your pairs of buttons are:

`button1.component.ts`:

```
import { button1, updateButton1 } from './buttons';
import type { ButtonInfo } from './buttons';

export class Button1Component {
   button1: ButtonInfo = button1;

   ...

   updateButton(update) {
       updateButton1(update);
   }
}
```

`button1.component.html`:

```
<div>
    ...
    <button (click)="button1.onClick()">
        {{button1.title}}
    </button>
</div>
```